# ament_copyright --add-missing gives KeyError: 'copyright_holder'

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get an error running `ament_copyright --add-missing`:

```
$ /opt/ros/eloquent/bin/ament_copyright --add-missing "Clyde McQueen" bsd2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/eloquent/bin/ament_copyright", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ament-copyright==0.8.1', 'console_scripts', 'ament_copyright')()
  File "/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ament_copyright/main.py", line 128, in main
    file_descriptors, name, licenses[args.add_missing[1]], args.verbose)
  File "/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ament_copyright/main.py", line 221, in add_missing_header
    header = license_.file_header.format(**{'copyright': copyright_})
KeyError: 'copyright_holder'
```

I see `copyright_holder` in the template, but I'm not sure how to set it: https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/blame/master/ament_copyright/ament_copyright/template/bsd2_header.txt

Perhaps this is a little-used feature, so nobody has noticed this bug? Workaround is easy, I'll just copy/paste the headers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353760/ament_copyright---add-missing-gives-keyerror:-%27copyright_holder%27/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2020-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While the bug has been fixed for Foxy (https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/pull/206) it hasn't been backported  yet.

As a temporary workaround you can apply the same patch to your local file `ament_copyright/main.py`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1